# How to remove columns to make this matrix full rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, kronecker-product

Let $X$ be an $n\times k$ real matrix with $\text{rank}(X)=k$, and let $Y$ be the $n^2\times nk$ matrix defined by

$$Y=[K_n +I_{n^2}][X\otimes I_n]$$

where $K_n$ denotes the [commutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) of order $n$. Then $\text{rank}(Y)=nk-\frac{k(k-1)}{2}$.

**Proof.** Let $USV'$ be an SVD decomposition of  $X$. Then

$$[U\otimes U][S\otimes I_n][V\otimes U]'$$ is an SVD decomposition of $X\otimes I_n$. Using the properties of the commutation matrix we get

$$Y=[U\otimes U][K_n +I_{n^2}][S\otimes I_n][V \otimes U]'$$

and so the rank of $Y$ is the same as the rank of $[K_n +I_{n^2}][S\otimes I_n]$. Now $S \otimes I_n= \begin{bmatrix}
D\\
0_{n(n-k)\times nk}
\end{bmatrix}$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix having $nk$ positive diagonal entries. Therefore the rank of $Y$ is the same as the rank of the matrix consisting of the first $nk$ columns of $K_n+I_{n^2}$.

Let $c_{ij}$ denote the $n(i-1)+j$ th column of $K_n+I_{n^2}$, where $1\leq i,j\leq n$. Using the explicit formula for the commutation matrix we have that

$$c_{i,j}=e_i \otimes e_j + e_j \otimes e_i$$

Since $e_i \otimes e_j=e_p \otimes e_q$ if and only if $(i,j)=(p,q)$ we see that $c_{i,j}=c_{p,q}$ if and only if $\{i,j\}=\{p,q\}$. Moreover if $c_{i,j}\neq c_{p,q}$ then $c_{i,j}$ and  $c_{p,q}$ are orthogonal.

Therefore there are $nk-\frac{k(k-1)}{2}$ linearly independent columns among the first $nk$ columns of $K_n+I_{n^2}$.

**Question:** Which columns of $Y$ can be removed in order to obtain a full rank matrix?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140265/discussion-on-question-by-alphie-how-to-remove-columns-to-make-this-matrix-full).